# Adding Data to urllib2.Request

Tags: python, github, urllib2, github-api

friends.

I'm writing a short script that will take a person's Github login and use it to query the Github API for an authorization token. Here's the code:

```
def getGithubAuth():
    "Get a Github auth token and return it"
    gist_data = json.dumps({"scopes":["gist"]})
    req = urllib2.Request(auth_url)
    base64str = base64.encodestring("%s:%s" % \
        (github_user, github_pass)).replace('\n','') # user/pass vars are declared elsewhere
    req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64str);
    req.add_data(gist_data) # <- including this makes problems

    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print "Something broke connecting to Github: %s" % e
        return None

    if response.getcode() == 200:
        jresp = json.loads('\n'.join(response.readlines()))[0]
        return jresp['token']
    return None
```

If I remove the `add_data` call, the request works and an auth token is returned. The problem is, I need to include the data passed to `add_data` in order to receive an auth token capable of interacting with Github's gist facility.

#### My two questions

1. How can I add this data to my request such that Github recognizes and accepts it?
2. I expect to find myself in a similar situation soon that will require sending a larger set of data; how would I pass a more complex set of values (like a large-ish dictionary with nested values, etc.)?

#### What I've Tried

I've found several Internet things saying that I should be using `urllib.urlencode` to encode the values before sending them, but I've not been able to make that work since `scopes` expects a list and `urlencode` expects a list of tuples.

I'm 100% sure I'm doing something stupid here, so if you could tell me what it is, I'd be grateful :)

Thanks — and please tell me if providing more information would make answering easier.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: When I include the stuff in `add_data`, the API returns a 404 "not found" error. I get a 200 if `add_data` is omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you're doing everything right. I tried your code and it works fine, with a minor modification.

Here's what happens:

When you don't include the data, the request being made is actually a GET request, which fetches the list of authorizations. This is not what you want since it doesn't create a new authorization.

When you do include the data, the request being made is a POST request, which is what you want. However, the status code returned is not 200, rather it is 201. So, just modify the code to check for 201 and get the token from the JSON body.

Comment: (i apologize for my first response, which i completely edited -- I made the same mistake as you -- assuming the response will be a 200, not a 201)

Answer (score 0):

Using `requests` is a little nicer:

```
app_name = 'your_app'

import requests, json

def create_github_oauth_token(user, password):

    # Check there isn't already an auth code for your app:
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/authorizations',
        auth=(user, password))
    for auth in r.json():
        if auth['note'] == app_name \
            and 'repo' in auth['scopes']:
            print "Retrieving existing token"
            print json.dumps(auth, indent=4)
            return auth['token']

    print "Creating new token"
    # Otherwise create a new token
    r = requests.post('https://api.github.com/authorizations',
        data=json.dumps({
            'scopes':['repo'],
            'note':app_name
            }),
        headers={'content-type':'application/json'},
        auth=(user, password)
    )
    return r.json()['token']
```